# Flask duplicates slug text within the url when redirecting

Tags: python, flask

I have an issue regarding Flask 2.2.5 and slug redirects.

I am currently using a ReverseProxy on a local server.  Running the application, I have the following:

```
@mainapp.route('/<slug>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def introduction(slug):
    Title = "Hello World"
    Start = "Welcome, press start to begin."
    Start_Button = "Start"
    if request.method == 'POST':
         return redirect(slug + "/nextpage")
```

Clicking on the button I would then see this URL show up

```
[09/Jul/2023 01:18:08] "GET /folder/slug_name/slug_name/nextpage
```

And then consequently not show the page at all.  What is the issue causing this bad redirect?

For reference

```
mainapp.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"] = "/folder" #Directory of the main or subfolder.
mainapp.wsgi_app = ReverseProxied(mainapp.wsgi_app,script_name=mainapp.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"])
```

Thanks.

Comment: The obvious answer is to do `redirect("nextpage")`  Because you added a slash at the end of the route, that's considered the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

You're already on the URL `/folder/slug_name/` so when you append `slug_name/next_page` and then redirect, it results in `slug_name` appearing twice and redirecting to a bad URL.

Instead do `redirect("nextpage")`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.  I will update the problem.